# Using htaccess to redirect host urls but not when they contain paths or parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What I would like to do is use htaccess to redirect (301, Permanent Redirect) simple host only urls to another domain but only when the url contains no path or parameters.

For example:

http://www.mydomain.com should redirect to http://www.myotherdomain.com and 
http://mydomain.com should redirect to http://myotherdomain.com

(which I have found plenty of examples for)

**but** a url like: 
http://www.mydomain.com/someimage.jpg or http://mydomain.com/js/coolJsScript.js should not be redirected at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this rule will match incoming URLs without any path:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://othersite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

You haven't stated exactly what you are trying to do here, but there might be an alternative, which is to check to see if a file exists, and redirect to your other site if it doesn't exist. This test would be something like

```
# Check if file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f

# it exists, so stop processing
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Redirect everything else
RewriteRule (.*) http://othersite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What I am dealing with is a single web host with multiple sub-domains. I had a site served from the root of the host and have since moved it to a sub-directory off the root. Host headers properly direct to my sub-domains, but I still need to be able to serve item's from the root. I want mydomain.com to redirect to blog.mydomain.com but I want to be able to serve mydomain.com/myavatar.jpg from the root of the existing mydomain domain, while pushing any simple requests for mydomain.com on over to blog.mydomain.com. Your secondary solution sounds more appropriate then what I was thinking.